# AutoFS with NTFS not mounting

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive, ntfs, automount

I've dabbled a bit into getting rid of udev for mounting ntfs usb-sticks at boot time and when hotplugging because it seems to have troubles with fuseblk when using systemd.

Since usbdisk is not a proper solution for me, because one of the disks I want to access with ownCloud if it's plugged and usbdisks does not provide a steady mount location, neither are any of the udisks wrappers, I had to go for autofs.

I added the following udev rule to create a proper symlink to the one disk being plugged. This symlinking works properly, so I guess it's not the problem:

```
KERNEL=="sd?1", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{product}=="Elements 10B8", ATTRS{serial}=="575836314134345334343938", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Western Digital", SYMLINK+="Elements"
```

Which results in:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr 26 02:25 /dev/Elements -> sdb1
```

Now, I used the following configuration:
to /etc/auto.master I did add

```
/media/usb      /etc/auto.usb --timeout=5
```

I created /etc/auto.usb with the following content

```
Elements        -fstype=ntfs-3g,gid=100,dmask=002,fmask=113,utf8,flush,rw,noatime,user  :/dev/Elements
```

I changed the BROWSE_MODE to yes, because I wanted to see if at least the files load properly.

```
BROWSE_MODE="yes"
```

I've even added the parameter to /etc/nsswitch.conf as described in the following bug report, but it didn't help.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files/+bug/488077

Now /media/usb/Elements gets created by autofs (dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Apr 26 02:22 Elements), which makes me believe the configuration SHOULD work.

Accessing it:

```
***@***:~$ ls -alt /media/usb/Elements/
ls: cannot access /media/usb/Elements/: No such file or directory
```

Now, starting automount manually with -f -v does not give any further information (for me):

```
***@***:~$ sudo automount -f -v
Starting automounter version 5.0.8, master map /etc/auto.master
using kernel protocol version 5.02
mounted indirect on /media/usb with timeout 5, freq 2 seconds
ghosting enabled
```

I did try to it with /dev/sdb1 as well, which didn't work either. I'm out of guesses - anyone?

Comment: Seems it's caused by AutoFS always adding th -s option to mount, which isn't supported by ntfs-3g. Any ideas how to prevent that?